# Show Json Array in Table Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, requirejs

I have an API that query the instagram API. I´m trying to consume my API and show the Tags Search in a table. The Json response is like this:

```
{"data":[{"media_count":13485788,"name":"argentina"},{"media_count":47097,"name":"argentinas"}]}
```

and This is my javascript code:
Model:

```
define([], function(){
  return {
    InstagramTag: "",
    exists: true,
    tags: []
  } ;

});
```

Controller:

```
define(["jquery", "events", "model"], function($, events, model) {

  function initialize() {
    $("#user-selection").change(function() {
      var TagName = $("#user-selection").val() ;
      console.log("Fetching information for " + TagName) ;
      $("*").css({"cursor": "wait"}) ;
      $.getJSON("/api/tag/" + TagName, function(data) {
        model.exists = true ;
        model.tags = data ;
      }).fail(function() {
        model.exists = false ;
        model.tags = [] ;
      }).always(function() {
        model.InstagramTag = TagName ;
        $("*").css({"cursor": "initial"}) ;
        events.trigger("model_updated") ;
      });
    }) ;
  }

  return { "initialize": initialize };

});
```

TagTable:

```
define(["underscore"], function(_) {

  var rowTemplate = _.template("<tr>" + 

    "<td><%= name %></td>" +
    "<td><%= media_count %></td>"

    "</tr>") ;

  var repoTable = _.template("<table id='repo-table' class='table'>" +
    "<thead>" +
      "<tr>" +
        "<th>name</th><th>media_count</th>" +
      "</tr>" +
    "</thead>" +
    "<tbody>" +
      "<%= tbody %>" +
    "</tbody>" +
    "</table>") ;

  function build(model, divName) {
    var tbody = "" ;
    _.each(model.tags, function(tag) {
      tbody += rowTemplate(tag) ;
    }) ;
    var table = repoTable({tbody: tbody}) ;
    $(divName).html(table) ;
  }

  return { "build": build } ;
}) ;
```

I get and error in the TagTable and I can´t show the Json array in the table.
Error:
 _.each(model.tags, function(tag) -- media_count is not defined.
I guest something is wrong when when I  read de Json Array but I don´t know how to fix this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that you expect `model.tags` to be an array. However, the JSON you get is an object that has a `data` field that has for value an array and you assign the *whole object* to `model.tags` instead of the field. To get  `model.tags` to be an array, you should assign the `data` field. So you should do this:

```
$.getJSON("/api/tag/" + TagName, function(data) {
  model.exists = true ;
  model.tags = data.data; // Change this line!
})...
```